# Div height 100% doesn't work. The height of the div remains adapted to the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've checked all resources in the net but can't fix the height: 100% not working in my div. I've tried setting the height of the html and body (also min-height), and all other known solutions.

```
<section id="home_Page">
        <div id="homeSection">
            <p class="testoHome osservato fadeInH">Esame di Stato 2022/2023</p>
            <p class="testoHome osservato fadeInH">Ciotola Emanuele</p>
            <p class="citazioneHomePage osservato fadeInW">"Il tempo"</p>
        </div>
        <div id="fotoRicordi">
            <img src="..." width="100%" oncontextmenu="return false;" draggable="false">
        </div>
</section>

#homeSection {
    background-image: url(Assets/images/GraffitoViaDellaPace.svg);
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: calc(45px + 1vw);
}
```

I want my home_Page to be 100% high. I tried with a height of 100vh but this doesn't suit me because vh doesn't also calculate, for example, the height of the chrome bar on mobile.
section x has a variable height as the photo inserted in it adapts to the size of the screen.

Comment: that's exactly what i'm looking for but dvh is not supported by many browsers, i can't use it

Comment: You can grab the heights with JS, or polyfill it with JS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/large-small-dynamic-viewport-units-polyfill?activeTab=readme

Comment: As the wiki itself says: "This library is pre-release quality. It should work but it requires more comprehensive testing on different devices. Please test it out and report any bugs you might encounter". And if you look at the supported devices they are even less than dvh. I need something more stable unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunately the dvh seems the only solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution :) If there's something I misunderstood let me know and I will edit it. I left your html the same and this is the css I added:

```
  body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #home_Page {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; // not sure if you want it full width, feel free to remove this line
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

I think the position property will help you a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately your approach doesn't work for me either

Comment: @THEMANUX darn it. What exactly isn't working? I might be misunderstanding what you need to accomplish. But I'd love to help

Comment: The height of my home_Page keeps adapting to the content instead of being 100%

Comment: @THEMANUX is the content smaller or bigger than 100%? In other words, is home_Page shrinking or growing to fit the content?

Comment: the content is smaller. It is like 200-300px. home_Page is shrinking to fit it